# how to parsing with ply-pyhton

Tags: python, parsing, yacc, ply

I'm studying over parsing with ply-python. I have some problems. My parse output is not exactly what I wanted but in the right order. so please help or suggest something that can help.
the first question is why does the parser take "F 100 R 90" but write just F 100?
the second one is why I have None as an output?

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

filepath = "C:/Users/Pc/source/repos/automata/text.txt"
file = open(filepath, "r")
program = file.read()

tokens = ('F', 'R', 'L', 'COLOR', 'PEN',
          'NUMBER', 
          'COLOR_TYPE',
          'LBRACKET','RBRACKET' )

t_F = r'F'
t_R = r'R'
t_L = r'L'
t_COLOR = r'COLOR'
t_PEN = r'PEN'

t_NUMBER = r"\d+"

t_COLOR_TYPE = r"K|Y|M|S"

t_LBRACKET = r'\['
t_RBRACKET = r'\]'

t_ignore = " \t"

def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += t.value.count("\n")

def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = lex.lex()
lexer.input(program)
for token in lexer:
    print(token)

"""   
precedence = (
        ('right','R'),
        ('right', 'F'),
        ('right','L'),
        ('right','PEN','COLOR'),
        )
"""
run = []

# start = 'instructions'

def p_statememt_expr(t):
    'statement : expression'
    run.append(t[1])
    print(t[1])
    print("p_statememt_expr")
    print(*t, "\n")

def p_expression_loop_type(t):
    'expression : L NUMBER LBRACKET expression RBRACKET' # !
    run.append( [ t[1],t[2], [ t[4] ] ] )
    print("p_expression_loop_type")
    print(*t, "\n")

def p_expression_loop_type1(t):
    'expression : L NUMBER LBRACKET instructions RBRACKET'
    run.append([t[1], t[2] , [ t[4] ] ])
    print("p_expression_loop1")
    print(*t, "\n")

def p_expression_loop_type2(t):
    'expression : L NUMBER LBRACKET instructions RBRACKET quality'
    run.append([t[1], t[2], [ t[4] ] ,t[6] ])
    print("p_expression_loop_type2")
    print(*t, "\n")

def p_expression_loop_type_3(t):
    'expression : L NUMBER LBRACKET instructions quality RBRACKET'
    run.append([t[1], t[2], [ t[4] ,t[5] ] ])
    print("p_expression_loop_type_3")
    print(*t, "\n")

def p_expression_loop_type4(t):
    'expression : L NUMBER LBRACKET instructions quality RBRACKET quality'
    run.append([t[1], t[2], [ t[4] ,t[5] ] ,t[7] ])
    print("p_expression_loop_type4")
    print(*t, "\n")

def p_expression_loop_type5(t):
    'expression : L NUMBER LBRACKET instructions quality RBRACKET instructions quality' # !
    run.append([t[8], t[1], t[2], [ t[5] ,t[4] ] ,t[7] ])
    print("p_expression_loop_type5")
    print(*t, "\n")

def p_instruction(t):
    '''instructions : F NUMBER R NUMBER
                    | R NUMBER
                    | F NUMBER
                  '''
    run.append([t[1],t[2]])
    print("p_instruction")
    print(*t, "\n")

def p_quality(t):
    '''quality : COLOR COLOR_TYPE
               | PEN NUMBER
               | COLOR COLOR_TYPE PEN NUMBER
               '''
    run.append([t[1],t[2]])
    print("p_quality")
    print(*t, "\n")

def p_error(t):
    print("Syntax error at '%s'" % t.value)
    print("p_error")
    print(*t, "\n")

parser = yacc.yacc()
parser.parse(program)
print(run)
```

output is

```
LexToken(L,'L',1,0)
LexToken(NUMBER,'36',1,2)
LexToken(LBRACKET,'[',1,5)
LexToken(L,'L',1,7)
LexToken(NUMBER,'4',1,9)
LexToken(LBRACKET,'[',1,11)
LexToken(F,'F',1,13)
LexToken(NUMBER,'100',1,15)
LexToken(R,'R',1,19)
LexToken(NUMBER,'90',1,21)
LexToken(PEN,'PEN',1,24)
LexToken(NUMBER,'2',1,28)
LexToken(RBRACKET,']',1,30)
LexToken(R,'R',1,32)
LexToken(NUMBER,'10',1,34)
LexToken(COLOR,'COLOR',1,37)
LexToken(COLOR_TYPE,'K',1,43)
LexToken(RBRACKET,']',1,45)
p_instruction
None F 100 R 90

p_quality
None PEN 2

p_instruction
None R 10

p_quality
None COLOR K

p_expression_loop_type5
None L 4 [ None None ] None None

p_expression_loop_type
None L 36 [ None ]

None
p_statememt_expr
None None

[['F', '100'], ['PEN', '2'], ['R', '10'], ['COLOR', 'K'], [None, 'L', '4', [None, None], None], ['L', '36', [None]], None]
```

in the text file I have this instruction

```
L 36 [ L 4 [ F 100 R 90 PEN 2 ] R 10 COLOR K ]
```

and they are meaning

```
F n -> go on n step
R n -> turn right n degree
L n -> Repeat the parentheses n times, so it will be loop
COLOR f -> f: line color
PEN n -> line thickness
```

finally if i have take the true parse output i will use them with turtle and draw something in GUI. for example drawing output of program in the text will be

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> why does the parser take "F 100 R 90" but write just F 100?

Because that's what your action says it should do:

````
# I abbreviated the rule for space
def p_instruction(t):
'''instructions : F NUMBER R NUMBER```
    run.append([t[1],t[2]])
````

The `R` and associated number are not used by the action.

Hint: You shouldn't assume that there are only one or two instructions. You need to right a grammar which accepts any number of commands. Also, there is no need to special case the other commands, not even Loop. A list of commands is just a list of commands.

> why I have None as an output?

Because you are using the semantic value of the non-terminal `instructions` but that non-terminal does not return any value. So its value is `None`. Instead of appending to `run`, you should build up the list by returning semantic values from each production, which you do by assigning to `p[0]`.

#### Additional hint:

I think I've said this before, but trying to cut and paste bits and pieces of a grammar designed for a completely different purpose (an expression evaluator) is not helping you at all. Figure out how Ply works and write your own grammar.